# Backbone Forms weird bug/behavior

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js, backbone-forms

**BRIEF:**

I write my custom backbone editor, but Backbone can't initialize it because can't find schema for it. Backbone looks for schema in `Form.editors` array at `backbone-forms.js`? *How can I register schema of my custom editor?*

**DETAILED:**

I use Backbone Forms which are initialized in the next way:

*backbone-forms.js*

```
var Form = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(options) {
    //.....
    //Check which fields will be included (defaults to all)
    var selectedFields = this.selectedFields = options.fields || _.keys(schema);
    _.each(selectedFields, function(key) {
      var fieldSchema = schema[key];
      fields[key] = this.createField(key, fieldSchema); // <==== Here troubles begins
    }, this);
  },
  //....
}, {
  //....
  editors: {} // <===== QUESTION: where I should put my custom editor in this array???
});
```

**Problem:** When Backbone creating new Form it calls `createSchema` method which looks like:

```
  createSchema: function(schema) {
    //........

    //PROBLEM: Form.editors[schema.type] is undefined
    schema.type = (_.isString(schema.type)) ? Form.editors[schema.type] : schema.type;

    return schema;
  }
```

and **Form.editors[schema.type] is undefined**. That means I can't create/render my custom editor!

**Question:** *Where/How I can register my custom editor in `Form.editors` array?*

Comment: Why don't you add "editors" directly inside your object instead of give the hash in the second arguments of extend ? (Did you try it ?)

Comment: @queval_j I fixed that by adding `Backbone.Form.editors.MyCustomEditor = MyCustomEditor;`

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the custom editor directly from within the schema, i.e. reference the function itself rather than a string:

```
var CustomEditor = Backbone.Form.editors.Base.extend({});

var form = new Backbone.Form({
  schema: {
    customField: { type: CustomEditor }
  }
});
```

Or, like you found, you can also add the editor to `Backbone.Form.editors` so you can use the string as a shortcut.